# Image css effect don't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, image

Hi and thanks for the support i don't know why the css image effect doesn't work in firefox.
Any ideas?

Many thanks

```css
.box-image-effect {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#000;
    height:217px;
    width:auto;
}
.image-effect:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
    -o-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
    transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
    opacity:0.5;
}
.image-effect {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-image-effect"><a href="http://209.227.255.112/cominshop2/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1371_048AS-5-SPORTBADIA-DSC01424.jpg"><img class="alignnone wp-image-129 size-medium" src="http://209.227.255.112/cominshop2/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1371_048AS-5-SPORTBADIA-DSC01424-290x217.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" width="290" height="217" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: your `img` tag does not have a class called `image-effect`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `.image-effect` class to your image

```css
.box-image-effect{
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
height:217px;
width:auto;
}

.image-effect:hover {
-webkit-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
  -o-transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
  transform:rotate(13deg) scale(1.5);
  opacity:0.5;
}
.image-effect {
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-image-effect">
  <a href="http://209.227.255.112/cominshop2/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1371_048AS-5-SPORTBADIA-DSC01424.jpg">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-129 size-medium image-effect" src="http://209.227.255.112/cominshop2/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1371_048AS-5-SPORTBADIA-DSC01424-290x217.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" width="290" height="217" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Please apply class `image-effect` to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The Class image-effect is not present on img tag.please add class **image-effect** to your image as:

```
<img class="alignnone wp-image-129 size-medium image-effect" src="http://209.227.255.112/cominshop2/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1371_048AS-5-SPORTBADIA-DSC01424-290x217.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" width="290" height="217" />
```